# What is the use of CountDown Latch in Kafka Listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have seen lot of articles where they use CountDown Latch in Kafka Listener , but I am not able to understand why its being used here , what happens when we increase the initial count in Latch , does it configure the number of messages listener can consume concurrently .

```
private CountDownLatch eventLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name}", containerFactory = "eventKafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.groupId}")
    public void eventListener(@Payload Event event, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
            @Nullable @Header("X-Retry") String retryCountHeader, Acknowledgment ack) {
        log.info("Received event message: {} from partition : {} and offset : {} ", event, partition, offset);
        try {
            persistEventToDB(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception occured : {}", e.getClass().getName());
            if (e instanceof DateTimeParseException) {
                log.info("Non Recoverable exception , hence sending to DLT without any retry for message : {}",
                        event);
                sendToDLT(event, null, false);
            } else {
                log.info("Sending to DLT for retry as message consumption failed for message {} ", event);
                sendToDLT(event, retryCountHeader, true);
            }
        } finally {
            ack.acknowledge();
            this.eventLatch.countDown();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't look into a testing part of those articles where the unit test uses this latch like: `eventLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

The point is that unit test is ran in one thread, but this `@KafkaListener` in the other, so to have some assertions in the test, you need to ensure some asynchronous barrier.

Comment: It would not be normal to add the latch to the actual listener, though, but use some other mechanism to count it down, e.g. injecting a mock or stub for `persistEventToDB`.

Comment: Correct, but looks like reporter has a concern from some non-official articles about `@KafkaListener`